# finding solution in real numbers, two variables

Tags: linear-algebra

With a problem expressed in a varaible $x$ like 
$$3y−6x=12$$

I can get a graph of that, or solve for $y$ in terms of $x$, but how do I find the real number (non-complex) solution, assuming, as is the case here, that there is one?

Comment: oops, I think I misread my graph. I thought the points on the axes were where it was intersecting the real number line! Please delete this question.

Comment: I'd actually love to see this question remain, as it gives future readers a hint: sometimes you can't solve a problem because you're trying to solve something different than what you're asked. In many areas of math, a tiny change converts something straightforward into something very difficult. So a good first step when you're stuck is, "Re-read the question, slowly, carefully, doubtingly."

Comment: If you want to delete your question then unaccept the accepted answer by clicking on the green tickmark again and then click on delete question below your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it represent a straight line every point is a solution

ie

You should have given two equations which would beCoincident lines

Infinite number of solutions. the pair of linear equations is consistent and dependent.

Comment: Where do you find a pair of equations?There is only one equation given...

Comment: The question itself is wrong

Comment: Your answer is also wrong...

Comment: Because there are no pair of equations to be a dependent system of equations...

Comment: I just explained him

Comment: Now see it please

Answer (score 1):

solving for $y$ we obtain:
$$3y=12+6x$$ dividing by 3 we get:
$$y=4+2x$$

Answer (score 1):

$$3y-6x=12$$ is of the form $y=mx+c$ which represents a straight line.We have infinite solutions.In fact for every real $x$ we have a corresponding $y$ satisfying the equation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting fractions while plotting graph, first you should make the equation simple as $$ y = 4 + 2x $$

Then when you get equation like in form & $y=f(x)$ then by putting ( natural numbers ) you get "y" for that value of "x".

Like this you don't get fractions for plotting graphs